# Fisher Information from Discretized Likelihood

Tags: discrete-data, fisher-information

I suppose this may sound like a general question, so sorry if it actually is.

How can I calculate the Fisher information for a log-likelihood which I have calculated for a discretized set of points. Is there any known reliable method for such thing? I could approximate derivatives numerically so it is certainly feasible, but I am ignorant with respect to any formal method (maybe I would have to adapt from other numerical methods, but I was hoping for something quick...)

Comment: by using finite differences?